# Serializing python object to python source code

Tags: python, json, serialization, code-generation

I have a python dictionary that I'd like to serialize into python source code required to initialize that dictionary's keys and values.

I'm looking for something like [`json.dumps()`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), but the output format should be Python not JSON.

My object is very simple: it's a dictionary whose values are one of the following:

1. built-in type literals (strings, ints, etc.)
2. lists of literals

I know I can build one myself, but I suspect there are corner cases involving nested objects, keyword escaping, etc. so I'd prefer to use an existing library with those kinks already worked out.

Comment: Python not Json? what are you talking about?

Comment: `'obj = json.loads(%r)' % json.dumps(some_dict)`? ☃

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most general case, it's not possible to dump an arbitrary Python object into Python source code. E.g. if the object is a socket, recreating the very same socket in a new object cannot work.

As aix explains, for the simple case, `repr` is explicitly designed to make reproducable source representations. As a slight generalization, the pprint module allows selective customization through the [PrettyPrinter](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#prettyprinter-objects) class.

If you want it even more general, and if your only requirement is that you get executable Python source code, I recommend to pickle the object into a string, and then generate the
source code

```
obj = pickle.loads(%s)
```

where `%s` gets substituted with `repr(pickle.dumps(obj))`.

Comment: PrettyPrinter looks like exactly what I was looking for.  The objects I'm trying to serialize are very simple-- a dictionary whose values are either literals or lists of literals.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`repr(d)` where `d` is your dictionary could be a start (doesn't address all the issues that you mention though).

Comment: Will repr() handle nesting, as long as the nested values are lists whose elements can be properly emitted by repr()?

Comment: also use import ast; ast.literal_eval(s) to read the dict back

Comment: @Spike Nice, thanks for pointing out `ast.literal_eval`. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use yaml

http://pyyaml.org/

YAML doesn't serialise EXACTLY to python source code. But the yaml module can directly serialise and deserialise python objects. It's a superset of JSON.

What exactly are you trying to do?